# Regex to accept any set of characters, and then remember and find that same set that was provided

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want regex to accept *any number of characters*, and then remember *that exact set of characters* and then look for it later in the line.

For example, if Regex saw the line begin with 'TheseCharacters', then I would want it to match the line if it saw 'TheseCharacters' occur later in the line.

Examples (all these would match):

`TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharacters.`

`Dog1, My favorite word is Dog1.`

The following would **not** match:

`Cakeman, oh I enjoy cakeboy.`

Is this outside the scope of regex, or is there a way to dynamically do this?

Comment: Theoretical science clearly tells that this is not possible using regular expressions. You need some sort of memory for that, so at least a turing machine instead of a finite state machine. The problem you describe is a non-regular one, it is too complex to be solved by a regular language. That can be proven, there is no way around that.

Comment: You could likely do something with grouping and backreferences.

Comment: What you obviously _can_ do is apply _two_ separate regular expressions: one to capture an arbitrary substring from the beginning of the string, the second to then try to match that captured substring further down.

Comment: Something like this would work for what you are talking about: [`(?:(\b\w+\b).*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/DuTbyn/1). This just looks for any block of letters that exists more than once in a string. You could anchor that to the start of the string to find just the first block of characters and match only if that exists later in the string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Would you mind describing what's happening there? And where the contents of the 'variable' are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little hard to tell what you are trying to do, but from what I understand, you could use grouping and backreferences to accomplish this. Something like this:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/^(\b\w+\b).*\b\1\b.*/i';

//should match
$string = "TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharacters";
$result = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "String 1 matches {$result} times: ".print_r($matches,true)."\n";

//match only with case insensitive flag, not an exact match in case
$string = "TheseCharacters, I really enjoy thesecharacters";
$result = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "String 1 matches {$result} times: ".print_r($matches,true)."\n";

//should match, doesn't require TheseCharacters to be at the end of the string.
$string = "TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharacters and some others";
$result = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "String 2 matches {$result} times: ".print_r($matches,true)."\n";

//no match, TheseCharacters has been changed to TheseLetters
$string = "TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseLetters";
$result = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "String 3 matches {$result} times: ".print_r($matches,true)."\n";

//no match, additional letters has been added to TheseCharacters
$string = "TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharactersasdf";
$result = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "String 4 matches {$result} times: ".print_r($matches,true)."\n";
```

which produces this output:

```
String 1 matches 1 times: Array
(
    [0] => TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharacters
    [1] => TheseCharacters
)

String 1 matches 1 times: Array
(
    [0] => TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharacters
    [1] => TheseCharacters
)

String 2 matches 1 times: Array
(
    [0] => TheseCharacters, I really enjoy TheseCharacters and some others
    [1] => TheseCharacters
)

String 3 matches 0 times: Array
(
)

String 4 matches 0 times: Array
(
)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/upNhm

And explanation of the pattern here: https://regex101.com/r/DuTbyn/2

And it's not really a "variable" that is being stored. It is a group, which you can reference later on by it's group number. So initially I am matching the first group of letters/numbers from the first start of the string (`^(\b\w+\b)`). Then followed by any number of characters and later matching whatever was captured in that first group. The matching entire string will be available in `$matches[0]` and the repeating string will be available in `$matches[1]`.

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, this is pretty much the only way. Other ways might be to match or split each word into the individual words into an array and simply use [array_count_values](https://php.net/array_count_values) to get a count of each word.